# How can I forward GLFW's keyboard input to another object?

Tags: opengl, c++, keyboard, glfw

I'm having trouble trying to execute keyboard events in a another class with GLFW3. The problem I'm having is that GLFW3 uses a static function for input as shown:

```
static UI u;
...
...
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    u.controls(window, key, action);
}
```

`u` is also static and controls holds the the input for WSAD keys (the only way I could get get key events). From here, pressing a key works displaying which key is pressed in the console window. The trouble I'm having is trying to used the key pressed to manipulate a variable in another class.

I have another class called MainMenu that has the function `update().` Is there a way I can use my UI class within this function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach with a static UI class. The usual way to "bounce" from a static callback to an instance function is to store something capable of making the jump in a place that is accessible from the static callback.

Most APIs, like GLFW and native Win32, that require these sorts of static callbacks provide a way to make the association above. GLFW windows have a pointer-sized block of storage that you can assign to: the *user pointer*. You can [get](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06) or [set](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) this user pointer as needed.

A very common pattern is to have some kind of `Game` class that has methods like "HandleKeyPress(Key key)" or whatnot. When you program starts, you create the `Game` object and do all your GLFW initialization, then stuff the `Game` pointer into the user data storage:

```
int main () {
  GLFWindow * window = ... create GLFW window ...
  Game game(... game constructor parameters ...);

  glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &game);

  ... main game loop ...
}
```

Then, your keyboard callback (and all other static callbacks) can unpack the `Game *` from user pointer storage and forward to it:

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
  Game * game = reinterpret_cast<Game *>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
  game->HandleKeyDown(...);
}
```

The `HandleKeyDown` method on the `Game` instance can forward along to your UI object if needed (or, if you really *only* need keyboard input for the UI object you could just stuff a pointer to your UI object in the user storage, however, stuffing something like the game or something higher-level is generally better since you only have one pointer per window to use).

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around that for now was in using a singleton object, when I needed to access the class I could just retrieve the pointer to the singleton:

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    InputManager * in_manager = InputManager::get_instance();
    in_manager->handle_key_press( params)
}
```

Somehting like that.